# How to setup html5 routing (client-side) on the loopback?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, html, routes, loopbackjs

What should I write in middleware.json (loopback), to operate html5 mode, for front-end routing?

I can use something looks like:
`app.all("/*", ...);` And return my index.html
But this solution is bad for loopback. I can override my middleware.json routes.
So I need some solution how configure it in middleware.json

Answer (score 0):

This is from the docs where they add a root.js route to serve the uptime of the API when you hit `/`. Just change it to serve your AngularJS index.html instead.

```
module.exports = function(server) {
  var router = server.loopback.Router();
  // could also use function that dynamically creates index.html, etc...

  router.get('/', <SEND index.html HERE>);

  server.use(router);
};
```

Alternatively, you can delete server/boot/root.js (or rename it) and then add static middleware as described here:

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Add+a+static+web+page

server/middleware.json:

```
...
  "files": {
    "loopback#static": {
      "params": "$!../client"
    }
  },
...
```